# returning pointer from function giving me random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I am working on a small console game on my free time and have come across a bug I can't seem to fix no matter what I try. I have tried a lot of different things with the pointers so this is just the latest version of my code. I have been searching around and a few questions other's have asked indicated I may be experiencing a memory leak, or that I am reading values from beyond my arrays (don't understand how). However, those questions have been solved without leaving me any hints as to what is wrong with my code.

Basically, I have a function called int `* spendAttribute(int point);`
Since anything created in that function is out of scope in my `main()` I want to take 6 int out of that function, and bring them into my `main()`.

I thought "hey why not use a pointer!" The function is supposed to return a pointer to an array created during the function, and paste it to another pointer created in `main()`, this has worked once before in my main(), but now it's not working and I have no clue why.

```
 int * spendAttribute(int point)
 {
 string choice;
 int hp,hpT,endur,endurT,dmg,dmgT,armor,armorT,agility,agilityT,evade,evadeT;
 while(condition)
  {
     //do a bunch of junk ....
  }
 int stats[6] = {hp,endur,dmg,armor,agility,evade}; 

 //some cout testing to see if values are correct (they are) 

 int* p_stats = new int [6]; //create a block of 6
 p_stats = &stats[0]; //point to the first value of stats array
 return p_stats; //return pointer
 delete [] p_stats; //delete blocks
 }
```

Note: I have tried without deleting the blocks and it still does not work. I tried this since I read that it might be a memory leak.I have tried it without using new at all.

```
main()
{

 //.... some junk
 while(main game loop)
   {
      int * pointer;
      cout << "*************** Enter 'begin' to commence ****************** " << endl ;
      cout << "*************** Enter 'spend' to use new attribute points ** " << endl ;
      cin >> beginChoice; //declared before while loop
      if(beginChoice == "spend")
      {

        cout << "total attributes: " << Bryan.returnAttribute() << endl ;
        pointer = spendAttribute(Bryan.returnAttribute()); //copy pointer
        cout << "TEST: " << endl ;
        cout << pointer[0] << endl ; //out put is a bunch of random numbers..
        cout << pointer[1] << endl ;
        cout << pointer[2] << endl ;
        cout << pointer[3] << endl ;
        cout << pointer[4] << endl ; 
        cout << pointer[5] << endl ; //SOME DAMN BUG HERE
        Bryan.addMaxHp(pointer[0]);
        Bryan.addEndurance(pointer[0]);
        Bryan.addDmg(pointer[0]);
        Bryan.addArmor(pointer[0]);
        Bryan.addAgility(pointer[0]);
        Bryan.addEvasion(pointer[0]);

        //after this character ends up having some ridiculous stats like -564553535% 
        //evasion or 9879967856 armor...

      }
    }
  }
```

This method of transferring the array over to main worked for me before in this exact file, so I don't know exactly how I am getting these errors or what's causing them. I have even tried deleting the previous pointer used to see if thats what was causing it but it wasn't.
Please Halp.

Comment: BTW, `delete [] p_stats;` is unreachable.

Comment: you should return `std::array<int, 6>` (or `std::vector`, or a appropriate `class Stat`).

Comment: I will look into std::array, have not used it before, thanks Jarod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you return a pointer to a local variable, and when that local variable goes out of scope you have a stray pointer.

And no, your allocation doesn't help, as you *reassign* the pointer to point to the local array, instead of copying into the allocated area. This of course means you also have a memory leak.

---

Regarding memory leak, you will still have a memory leak even when you fix the above problem. The reason being that you return from the function *before* you `delete[]` the pointer, and `return` returns from the function immediately, all code after a `return` statement is dead code. That means every time you call the function, it will allocate new memory which will never be free'd.

There are two obvious solutions to both the problems above: One is to allocate memory, *copy the array* into the allocated memory, and returning the pointer, and in the caller you do `delete[]` on the pointer.

The second solution is to pass in an array as argument, and use that instead of the local `stats` array.

Comment: not following you.... :/ 
The reason I tried doing it this way was because somehow I was successful with it before, is it because of the while loop that it goes out of scope?

Comment: no, `stats` is a local variable to `spendAttribute` so it is destroyed when that function returns. If it appeared to work once it is because you were accessing memory you didn't own, and it so happened that no other part of the program had overwritten that memory yet.

Comment: @user3743533 `stats` goes out of scope when the `spendAttribute` function returns. And as `p_stats` points to the `stats` array, you will return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Oh I see, so I'm returning a pointer to an array that is no longer in scope, so the pointer points to something that doesn't exist basically.

Comment: In your second solution, I should create an empty array in `main()`, pass it as an argument to `int * spendAttribute()` and then copy the stats[6] to that array? then return it to main using a pointer?

Comment: @user3743533 If you pass an array to `spendAttribute`, you don't need the local `stats` array, instead use the passed argument directly. You also don't need to return a pointer, just use the local (in `main`) array that you passed to the `spendAttribute`.

Comment: Sorry Joachim, how would I go about using `delete[]` in the caller? Do you mean `delete[]` after calling spendAttribute in main?

Comment: @user3743533 Yes, if you allocate memory in the function, and return a pointer to it, you need to free that memory somewhere when you're done with it.

Comment: I ended up just running an array as an argument through the function, instead of assigning it to a pointer. Much easier, yet I'll prob look into those more complicated alternatives later.

Answer (score 0):

`p_stats` is a pointer to int.

First you assign it to a newly allocated place in memory.

Then you move the pointer to point to local storage and return that. My guess is that you really wanted to return `stats`. Your options are:

- Returns std::vector< int >. Probably simplest.
- Modify your function to take a buffer to data and a length and fill it in.
- Return `std::array` if available and you know it will be a fixed size of 6.

Although you could copy the data into `p_stats` then return that, it is not ideal because the calling function is then responsible to delete the data later.

If the fields have different meanings, you might want to create a struct with meaningful names for the values, and get your function to return that struct. e.g.

```
struct SpendAttribute // in header
{
   int hp;
   int endur;
   int dmg;
   int armor;
   int agility:
   int evade
};

SpendAttribute spendAttribute( int point )
{
     SpendAttribute res;
  // enter code here
     return res;
}
```

There is a final option of putting the data into a smart-pointer like `boost::shared_array<int>` or you can use `shared_ptr` with an array-deleter.

For now, just return `std::vector<int>`

Comment: how would I go about deleting the data during the caller function?
Where would that go?

Comment: The data should not be deleted until it is no longer needed.

Comment: thanks for the alternatives, I wish I could upvote you but my reputation is too low :(

Comment: You could accept it but then you'd unaccept the other one. Incidentally when you ask a question you should accept the best answer, not necessarily the first one posted.